# How to find files based on timestamp

Tags: linux, find, date

How to find files that were created or modified based on a particular timestamp.

Let's say timestamp be `date +%d-%m-%y_%H.%M`

Could you suggest a command which fetches files based on a particular a timestamp ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the following command:

```
find /path/to/dir -newermt "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" -not -newermt "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss+1"
```

This command will list file in the folder `/path/to/dir`  modified between `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` and `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss + 1 second`

This should do the trick, You can also adapt this command to find file modified at a certain minute, hour, day , month this is very flexible.

If you want to find file by access time, you can tune it like this:

```
find /path/to/dir -newerat "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" -not -newerat "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss+1"
```

And if you want only the creation time:

```
find /path/to/dir -newerct "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" -not -newerct "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss+1"
```

This command search between the two date you mention the first date being inclusive and the second exclusive; it find file modified at or after `date 1` and before `date 2`.

you want more information look at this blog article it's nice: [Find Files Modified On Specific Date](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-osxfind-files-by-date/)

Comment: Thank you Kiwy it is working perfectly as my requirements and do we need to use same kind of time format for find command??

Comment: I have no idea I can't manage to find more information about the date format but this one works properly.